# Multiple join SQL Query Optimization for report

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working to generate a report from a database customers populate data into through a web application. Some customers have data in both the east/west data buckets and some are just one or the other.

I've put together this SQL query and it works but I'm wondering if I am wasting resources and how it will perform when the data grows (probably 10x in the next 12 months).

Most of my comfort in SQL is simple reads/writes. Something this large used to be 10 queries dumped into excel and then combined and I'm trying to get away from that. This was my first attempt. I appreciate any help.

```
select 
  "Account Name", 
  "HAP Sales Rep", 
  "HAP End Date", 

  /*east*/
  "groupeast Group Start", 
  "Total east Groups Created", 
  "Total east Groups Completed", 
  "Total east Groups Cancelled", 
  "Total Active east Groups", 
  "east recipients", 
  "east Outcomes", 

  /*west*/
  "groupwest Group Start", 
  "Total west Groups Created", 
  "Total west Groups Completed", 
  "Total west Groups Cancelled", 
  "Total Active west Groups", 
  "west recipients", 
  "west Outcomes" 
FROM 
  (
    (
      select 
        id, 
        name as "Account Name" 
      from 
        datmodel.accountinfo
    ) as ai 
    left outer join (
      select 
        accountid, 
        min(startdate) as "groupeast Group Start" 
      from 
        datmodel.managegroup 
      where 
        groupmodel = 'east' 
        and isdeleted NOT IN (1, 2) 
      group by 
        accountid
    ) as gseast on gseast.accountid = ai.id 
    left outer join (
      select 
        accountid, 
        min(startdate) as "groupwest Group Start" 
      from 
        datmodel.managegroup 
      where 
        groupmodel = 'west' 
        and isdeleted NOT IN (1, 2) 
      group by 
        accountid
    ) as gswest on gswest.accountid = ai.id 
    left outer join (
      select 
        accountid, 
        count(accountid) as "Total east Groups Created" 
      from 
        datmodel.managegroup 
      where 
        groupmodel = 'east' 
        and isdeleted <> 1 
      group by 
        accountid
    ) as teast on teast.accountid = ai.id 
    left outer join (
      select 
        accountid, 
        count(accountid) as "Total west Groups Created" 
      from 
        datmodel.managegroup 
      where 
        groupmodel = 'west' 
        and isdeleted <> 1 
      group by 
        accountid
    ) as twest on twest.accountid = ai.id 
    left outer join (
      select 
        accountid, 
        count(accountid) as "Total east Groups Completed" 
      from 
        datmodel.managegroup 
      where 
        groupmodel = 'east' 
        and isdeleted = 3 
      group by 
        accountid
    ) as cmeast on cmeast.accountid = ai.id 
    left outer join (
      select 
        accountid, 
        count(accountid) as "Total west Groups Completed" 
      from 
        datmodel.managegroup 
      where 
        groupmodel = 'west' 
        and isdeleted = 3 
      group by 
        accountid
    ) as cmwest on cmwest.accountid = ai.id 
    left outer join (
      select 
        accountid, 
        count(accountid) as "Total east Groups Cancelled" 
      from 
        datmodel.managegroup 
      where 
        groupmodel = 'east' 
        and isdeleted = 2 
      group by 
        accountid
    ) as ceast on ceast.accountid = ai.id 
    left outer join (
      select 
        accountid, 
        count(accountid) as "Total west Groups Cancelled" 
      from 
        datmodel.managegroup 
      where 
        groupmodel = 'west' 
        and isdeleted <> 2 
      group by 
        accountid
    ) as cwest on cwest.accountid = ai.id 
    left outer join (
      select 
        accountid, 
        count(accountid) as "Total Active east Groups" 
      from 
        datmodel.managegroup 
      where 
        groupmodel = 'east' 
        and isdeleted = 0 
      group by 
        accountid
    ) as taeast on taeast.accountid = ai.id 
    left outer join (
      select 
        accountid, 
        count(accountid) as "Total Active west Groups" 
      from 
        datmodel.managegroup 
      where 
        groupmodel = 'west' 
        and isdeleted = 0 
      group by 
        accountid
    ) as tawest on tawest.accountid = ai.id 
    left outer join (
      select 
        id, 
        MIPSales Repc as "HAP Sales Rep", 
        startupPlanEndDatecc as "HAP End Date" 
      from 
        datmodel.accountinfo 
      where 
        startupPlanEndDatecc > CURRENT_DATE
    ) as cons on cons.id = ai.id 
    left outer JOIN (
      select 
        p.accountid, 
        count(p.id) as "west recipients" 
      from 
        datmodel.recipients as p 
        inner join datmodel.managegroup as mg on mg.id = p.groupid 
        and mg.groupmodel = 'west' 
        and mg.isdeleted NOT IN (1, 2) 
      group by 
        p.accountid
    ) as ppat on ppat.accountid = ai.id 
    left outer JOIN (
      select 
        p.accountid, 
        count(p.id) as "east recipients" 
      from 
        datmodel.recipients as p 
        inner join datmodel.managegroup as mg on mg.id = p.groupid 
        and mg.groupmodel = 'east' 
        and mg.isdeleted NOT IN (1, 2) 
      group by 
        p.accountid
    ) as prpat on prpat.accountid = ai.id 
    left outer JOIN (
      select 
        ai.id, 
        count(p.id) as "west Outcomes" 
      from 
        (
          select 
            id, 
            groupid 
          from 
            datmodel.recipientoutcome 
          where 
            GroupModel = 'west'
        ) as p 
        inner join datmodel.managegroup as mg on mg.id = p.groupid 
        inner join datmodel.accountinfo as ai on mg.accountid = ai.id 
      group by 
        ai.id
    ) as westout on westout.id = ai.id 
    left outer JOIN (
      select 
        ai.id, 
        count(p.id) as "east Outcomes" 
      from 
        (
          select 
            id, 
            groupid 
          from 
            datmodel.recipientoutcome 
          where 
            GroupModel = 'east'
        ) as p 
        inner join datmodel.managegroup as mg on mg.id = p.groupid 
        inner join datmodel.accountinfo as ai on mg.accountid = ai.id 
      group by 
        ai.id
    ) as eastout on eastout.id = ai.id
  )
```

Comment: is the GroupModel column indexed in the tables you use ?

Comment: No. From what I gather, the only indices are the ID columns on each table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do it as an aggregate query?
It tends to be easier to read too...
eg:

```
select 
accountid,
SUM(CASE WHEN groupmodel = 'east' and isdeleted <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Total east Groups Created",
...
SUM(CASE WHEN groupmodel = 'west' and isdeleted <> 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 
MIN(CASE WHEN groupmodel = 'west' and isdeleted NOT IN (1, 2)THEN startdate ELSE NULL END ) as "groupwest Group Start" 
...
etc
from 
datmodel.managegroup 
GROUP BY accountid
```

Comment: Thank you John. I'll give this a try later. It makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the subqueries in your report are from the same two tables. You can exploit this by moving the logic into CASE statements in the SELECT clause instead of using subqueries. The first 12 or so columns of your query could be done like this:

```
select a.id,
       a.name as "Account Name",
       min(case when g.isdeleted NOT IN (1, 2) and g.groupmodel = 'east' then g.startdate
           else null end) AS "groupeast Group Start",
       min(case when g.isdeleted NOT IN (1, 2) and g.groupmodel = 'west' then g.startdate
           else null end) AS "groupwest Group Start" ,
       sum(case when g.groupmodel = 'east' and g.isdeleted <> 1 then 1
           else 0 end) AS "Total east Groups Created" ,
       sum(case when g.groupmodel = 'west' and g.isdeleted <> 1 then 1
           else 0 end) AS "Total west Groups Created" ,
       sum(case when g.groupmodel = 'east' and g.isdeleted = 3 then 1
           else 0 end) AS "Total east Groups Completed"  ,
       sum(case when g.groupmodel = 'west' and g.isdeleted = 3 then 1
           else 0 end) AS "Total west Groups Completed"  ,
       sum(case when g.groupmodel = 'east' and g.isdeleted = 2 then 1
           else 0 end) AS "Total east Groups Cancelled"  ,
       sum(case when g.groupmodel = 'west' and g.isdeleted = 2 then 1
           else 0 end) AS "Total west Groups Cancelled"   ,
       sum(case when g.groupmodel = 'east' and g.isdeleted = 0 then 1
           else 0 end) AS "Total Active east Groups" ,
       sum(case when g.groupmodel = 'west' and g.isdeleted = 0 then 1
           else 0 end) AS "Total Active west Groups"
from datmodel.accountinfo a
left outer join datmodel.managegroup g on g.accountid = a.id
group by a.id, a.name
```

Some of the other columns may still need to be done with subqueries, or you might be able to incorporate them in the same way, I'll leave that up to you.